# Object Shows up fine in Editor Render Shading Mode, but not in Final Render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

As you can see below, when I render my scene, the icing from my doughnut disappears, however if you zoom in on the render, you can see some faint traces of the pink icing. Why does the final render (pic 1) not look like the render shading in object mode from the perspective of the camera (pic 2)?

[Here is my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihHt700TxKHsefFoFa9gn2IUDPPlwYcW/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Render]

[image: Object Mode with Render Shading]

Comment: Please read through the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: Hey @cegaton, I read through this earlier, but my issue seems to be different, my object didn't disappear completely, you can still see pieces of it if you look at the first image. It is almost like the doughnut is expanding in the render and blocking the icing. I'm a noob at blender and it's possible I have something silly like overlapping nodes/faces, but am unsure of how to check or if it is a different issue.